# "What went down"

Tags: slang

I want to know the actual meaning of "what went down" is it the same as "What happened" if so, could someone make a sentence with "what went down" replacing "what happened? forgive the rendundancy

Comment: Past tense of "What's going down", this is a slang term I've heard used in the 70's.  I can find no reference to it online.  Also similar, the expression, "What's the haps?"

Comment: If something *went down*, as opposed to simply *happened*, the usual implication is that ***there was a plan*** - and events either proceeded according to that plan, or (more likely) something happened that disrupted the plan.

Comment: I can't find a reference for you at the moment due to location (hence a comment) but it appears that the phrase evolved and shortened from "going down in the history books," as in "being written down in a history book."

Comment: I'll note (echoing Jason) that the phrase "going down" is an idiom for something that is currently happening.  I'm reasonably certain that I heard this phrase in the 60s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, broadly speaking "what went down" is synonymous with "what happened". It's a slang term, particularly prevalent in the areas of crime and law enforcement, and often refers to a sequence of events, rather than just a single incident. It may also include some element of *completeness*, describing not just what happened, but also why. For example:

> "Okay," said the officer, sitting down across from the suspect. "Tell me what happened."

can become

> "Okay," said the officer, sitting down across from the suspect. "Tell me what went down."

It is somewhat implied that the officer is asking for the full sequence of events, not just "he got shot".

Answer (score 2):

"What happened?" and "What went down?" are not interchangeable expressions.

- **[go down](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-down)** (happen): (Cambridge Dictionary) ​

  > ***US slang*** If an event such as a crime or a deal goes down, it happens:
  >
  > I tried to tell Tyrell what was going down, but he wouldn't listen.
- **[go down:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down)** ([idioms.freedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down))

  > 2. To occur, happen, or unfold, as of an event or action.
  >
  >    *We need to figure out what went down here before we can press any
  >      charges.*
  > 3. . Sl. to happen.
  >
  >    *Hey, man! What's going down? Something strange is going down around
  >      here.*
  > 4. Occur, take place, as *in Really crazy behavior was going down in the sixties.* [Slang; mid-1900s]

"Yes! Go down, for an event, means happen.( From [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-it-went-down-happened-go-down.2562272/))

Examples: *It's going down now. When do you plan for this to go down?* ***This is usually used in the context of crime or law enforcement.*** ***It would be unusual to say "We're planning a company picnic. It'll go down on June 14."***

Answer (score 1):

Past tense of *what's going down*

> verb - intransitive
>
> as a greeting, a rhetorical question asking about what's happening.
>
> Hey man, what's goin' down
>   ([Online slang dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/go-down)) 
>   ?

However while *what's going down* is usually rhetorical, *what went down* is interrogative and actually asking *what happened*?

Example sentence:

> I heard Joe came to see you last night, that sounds like trouble. What
>   went down?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the limitation of the phrase to criminal or similar activity. Also to the limitation to planned activity. In my experience, the phrase tends to refer to notable occurrences of any sort, planned or unplanned. Occurrences of some interest, including but not limited to dramatic happenings.

"Did you hear that the festival out at Ryan's Lake is on? They just said it's going down like the middle of August. Excellent!"

"Hey, what went down at Jason's party on Saturday? I hear Tommy and Michael got into it over a chick. What happened?"

"You are not going to believe it went I tell you what's going down with Taisha and Joey. For starters, Joey is staying on my couch right now."

The person above who notes that it probably wouldn't e used in announcing a company picnic is noticing that the phrase is hippie/hipster-speak. The inappropriacy is about social context, not denotational meaning.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question *is it the same as "What happened?"*

Answer (score 0):

I think it does. Within a particular social cohort (young hippie/hipster or still talking like one), "What went down...?"  means "What interesting/notable thing happened?" At least that's my sense of the expression.